# Help in a proof in Fulton's algebraic curves book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm reading [Fulton's algebraic curves](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) book and I didn't understand this proof of proposition 7 (page 106) very well:

[image]

So I have the following doubts:

1. I didn't understand why $\text{ord}_P(f')\ge -N$. I know that $\text{ord}_P(h)\ge -N$, $\text{ord}_P(g)\ge -N$, $\text{ord}_P(h')\ge -N$, but I don't know how to get $\text{ord}_P(f')\ge -N$ using these facts.
2. Why the fact $\text{ord}_P(g')\ge -N$ implies each term belongs to $\mathcal O$?

Any help is very welcome.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: For (1): it should be true that all elements of $R$ have valuation $\geq 0$, and $\operatorname{ord}_P(h) = 0$ since it doesn't even vanish at $P$. For (2): the inequality implies that each term has nonnegative valuation w.r.t. $\operatorname{ord}_P$, and that implies membership in $\mathcal{O}$.

Comment: @Hoot Thank you for your comment. I have a question, Why isn't $-N$ negative? thank you again.

Comment: $-N$ probably is negative; any large enough $N$ should work. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @hoot So I didn't understand why the inequality implies that each term has nonnegative valuation. $\text{ord}_P(g')$ could be negative right?

Comment: It could be, but $g'$ never sits alone here. For example, the last term is $t^Ng'$ and $\operatorname{ord}_P(t) = 1$ by its very definition, so $\operatorname{ord}_P(t^Ng') = N\operatorname{ord}_P(t) + \operatorname{ord}_P(g') = N + \operatorname{ord}_P(g') \geq N-N = 0$.

Comment: Of course thank you very much again. Just one more doubt. It isn't related with the initial question  (be free if you don't want to answer). Why $\text{ord}_P(f_x(x,y)x'+f_y(x,y)y')\ge 0$? The problem is I don't know anything about the order of these derivatives. I'm so sorry to ask you too much. Thanks again!

Comment: The derivatives are all in $R$, so they have valuations $\geq 0$.